# Unable to get all image url in for looop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, feedparser

I want to output all avaible images from rss feed. My code only getting first image of the feed .. help me to get all imagess

```
 import feedparser
    d = feedparser.parse('http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml')
    e = d["entries"][0]
    n = e["media_thumbnail"][0]["url"]
    for i in n:
       print (n)
```

Comment: What do you think is happening here: `n = e["media_thumbnail"][0]["url"]`?

Comment: @DirtyBit it getting thumbnail url..

Answer (score 0):

This code will solve your problem ,You just need to select whole entries using index methood

```
import feedparser
d = feedparser.parse('http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml')
e = d["entries"][0:]

for i in e:
    link = i["media_thumbnail"][0]["url"]
    print(link)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `[0:]` in this context?